# what symmetric keys we can use in angular cryptography?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, ionic-framework, cryptography

I am using ionic to develop my mobile application.
To achieve encryption, am using angular mdo cryptography.

https://github.com/middleout/angular-cryptography/blob/master/mdo-angular-cryptography.js

Application has Remember Me feature where initially I save server token in localStorage and then check the same while launching the app.

Encryption is done to encrypt sensitive details only which are stored in localStorage.
I am stuck in knowing the key that can be used in the above angular cryptography library.
I tried device UUID but seems it gets changed while app. upgrade or while ad-hoc testing builds.

Any ideas of what we can use as key so that it remains same irrespective of install or delete or upgrade ?
Application is targeted for Android,iOS and Windows

Help is appreciated !

Comment: The key is getting from the user side. when you install app just ask a key for encryption

Comment: @AnishChandran Ya.. but key from whom? user ? As I said, uuid won't work.I want possibililities which can work for all three environment.

Comment: Key means its like a password . It collect form the user side (App user)

Comment: @AnishChandran Ok .. Since application has fetaure of Remember Me as mentioned above, where will this password actually stored ? In lcoalStorage ? Again it is exposed to client.

Comment: You can encrypt that password with a common key and store it localStorage.Common key is stored in server

Comment: @AnishChandran u mean get key from server and do the maths in client ? In that case there may be performance hit where I need to call service each time app. is killed and re-launched since I need key ..

Comment: options: 1. known pw from user, entered each boot. 2. unknown pw saved in clear in localStorage 3. unknown pw sent from server each boot.

Comment: @dandavis thanks .. can u pls clarify point 2 .. How to generate that pwd ? Also application has remember me feature, so I expect that to remain same even when the app. is relaunched

Comment: the "remember me" part is for identifying the user to the server, the password part is to decrypt localStorage; you cannot combine the 2 concerns. use `crypto.getRandomValues` to generate an unknown password.